# How to put parentheses around a value which is bound using knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I have an element which is binding a value like this:

```html
<span data-bind="text: myValue"></span>
```

I am going to show the value in the UI in parentheses without creating a new function. Is it possible to do it inside the element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're building a string, just evaluate the observable and concatenate:

```
<span data-bind="text: '(' + myValue() + ')'"></span>
```

To check for the empty value, just do the following:

```
<span data-bind="text: myValue() ? '(' + myValue() + ')' : '' "></span>
```

Comment: Thanks @dperry It is working. But when the 'myValue' is null it is going to show empty parenthesis. How can I make it conditional?

Comment: Working fine,KO is very tough to understand (:

Answer (score 3):

[The answer by @dperry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33486531/419956) using `text: myValue() ? '(' + myValue() + ')' : ''` is great for a quick fix, and I've used that approach on many occasions. It's also *technically* what you asked for (since you mention not wanting to create "a new function", which I take it means you don't want to create code behind).

However, especially when things get more complex/cluttered as with the `?:` ternary operator, I find that you typically *do* want to do this in View Models. IMHO view models are *meant* for this kind of task, because of potential reuse as well as unit testability.

So I'm still going to offer an alternative, if not for OP then for others that land here through searching.

Knockout has [`computed` observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) for this purpose:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.myValue = ko.observable(null);

  self.myValueTxt = ko.computed(function() {
    return !!self.myValue() ? "("+self.myValue()+")" : "";
  });
};
```

Use it like this:

```html
<span data-bind="text: myValueTxt"></span>
```

Now you can reuse `myValueTxt` in several places in your UI, you can unit test it and feel safe when changing the logic (e.g. changing the parentheses, or the empty string on null values).

---

Here's a full example that shows unit tests along the computed:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.myValue = ko.observable(null);

  self.myValueTxt = ko.computed(function() {
    return !!self.myValue() ? "("+self.myValue()+")" : "";
  });
};

QUnit.test("Can construct default ViewModel", function(assert) {
  assert.ok(!!new ViewModel());
});

QUnit.test("Default ViewModel has null myValue", function(assert) {
  assert.strictEqual(new ViewModel().myValue(), null);
});

QUnit.test("Can set and retrieve myValue", function(assert) {
  var vm = new ViewModel();
  vm.myValue("test test");
  assert.strictEqual(vm.myValue(), "test test");
});

QUnit.test("Default ViewModel has empty string myValueTxt", function(assert) {
  assert.strictEqual(new ViewModel().myValueTxt(), "");
});

QUnit.test("ViewModel with null myValue has empty string myValueTxt", function(assert) {
  var vm = new ViewModel();
  vm.myValue(null);  
  assert.strictEqual(vm.myValueTxt(), "");
});

QUnit.test("ViewModel with empty string myValue has empty string myValueTxt", function(assert) {
  var vm = new ViewModel();
  vm.myValue("");  
  assert.strictEqual(vm.myValueTxt(), "");
});

QUnit.test("ViewModel myValueTxt is wrapped myValue", function(assert) {
  var vm = new ViewModel();
  vm.myValue("test");  
  assert.strictEqual(vm.myValueTxt(), "(test)");
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.20.0.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.20.0.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="qunit"></div>
```